# How to use gmp-mpir-mpfr in eclipse correctly?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, gmp, mpfr, mpir

I've managed to to use mpfr-mpir-gmp in CodeBlocks but I want to in eclipse C++:

When I compile the code it compiles and build but if I run the project it says: "error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

So can anyone show me how to configure eclipse to use gmp-mpifr-mpir correctly?

- If I compile from a terminal:

  ```
  g++ -lmpir -lmpfr -lgmp myEclpiseMPFRMPIRproj.cpp
  ```

then :

```
./a.out
```

It works fine and doesn't complain about the same problem. So I think I don't know how to pass those flags `-lgmp, -lmpir -lmpfr`.

Thank you.

Comment: Again, using both gmp and mpir doesn't make sense, pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out after thousands of attempts without giving up. I am happy to share it for someone who may face the same problem:

When I've built and installed "gmp, mpfr, mpir" I've used `sudo make install` so the library is in `/usr/local` thus when I create a project with Eclipse-CDT everything is there only I add the flag to the linker:

```
 Project->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Linker->Command and add:

g++ -lgmp -lmpir -lmpfr
```

- Apply and Close. Now build and run. It works fine!

N.B: The problems I've faced already because I've add the `library paths and files` and `include paths` so I've removed them all.